# How to set header layout of the DatePickerDialog in android

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I'm creating a DatePickerDialog in android, I want my datepickerdialog look like the left dialog in the image. But when I write my own code, it just horizontal the text date (dialog on the right)
What should I do?
[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbApR.png)

```
package com.example.luc.myapplication;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.app.Dialog; 
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Use the current date as the default date in the date picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog =  new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    return dialog;
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    //Do something with the date chosen by the user
  LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    view.setLayoutParams(layout.getLayoutParams());
    TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("Date changed...");
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\nYear: " + year);
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\nMonth: " + month);
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\nDay of Month: " + day);

    String stringOfDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n\nFormatted date: " + stringOfDate);
}
}
```

I call the dialog when click a button in MainActivity

Comment: Please provide your `layout.xml`

Comment: my layout just has a button, I show a datepickerdialog i click a button.

Answer (score 1):

I would first change your layout to this, it will give you more control

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#008d7f"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Friday"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#009688"
    >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/week_day"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="MAY"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/day_of_month"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="8"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/week_day"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/year"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="2017"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/day_of_month"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and change you java to:

```
package com.example.luc.myapplication;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.app.Dialog; 
import java.util.Calendar;

 /**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //Use the current date as the default date in the date picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog =  new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    return dialog;
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
  //Do something with the date chosen by the user
  LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    view.setLayoutParams(layout.getLayoutParams());
    TextView tv_dayofweek = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.day_of_week);
    TextView tv_month = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.month);
    TextView tv_dayofmonth = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.day_of_month);
    TextView tv_year = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.day_of_week);
    tv.setText("Date changed...");
    tv_year.setText(tv.getText() + "\nYear: " + year);
    tv_month.setText(tv.getText() + "\nMonth: " + month);
    tv_dayofmonth.setText(tv.getText() + "\nDay of Month: " + day);

    String stringOfDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\n\nFormatted date: " + stringOfDate);
    }
}
```

Just tested and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how can i get the header of DatePickerDialog and change it's layout. the "onDateSet" method is used to set text in MainActivity layout not relavant to my DatePickerDialog.

Comment: there is a TextView "tv" in MainActivity( the MainActivity layout has two element TextView and Button)... sorry I forgot to tell you

Comment: what you you mean with `get the header of DatePickerDialog and change it's layout`?

Comment: I want to change the horizontal text(2017, Sun May 7) to vertical look like the image above. I dont know how to call this line of text, I think it is header of the DatepickerDialog

Comment: Did you try the above and what happened? I don't understand what you are struggling with. If I understand you correctly you have a `MainActivity` with a `TextView` and a `Button` then when the user click the button the datepickerdialog shows and when the user chooses a date it is displayed in the `TextView` in `MainActivity`?

Comment: yes, H.Brooks That exactly what you say. finally,I has just found the answer on google, The layout of DatePickerDialog is diffrent when use on android 5.0(with vertical align text in the head of dialog) and 6.0( with horizontal text in the head). by the way, thank you so much. Have a good day!

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Please mark my answer as helpful.

Comment: can we have the same view as android 5.0 for android above 5.0 final?
you found the answer but why you didn't share it here? :D unbelievable